# How to print the names of files from a folder?

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to print the names of all the files from a folder directory. I have a folder called "a", and in that folder there are 3 NC files, lets call them "b","c","d", whose directory I want to print. How would I do this?

For example, given my path to the folder is

```
path=r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Testing\\a"
```

I want to print the directories to all the files in the folder "a", so the result should print:

```
C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Testing\\a\\b.nc
C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Testing\\a\\c.nc
C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Testing\\a\\d.nc
```

So far, I've tried

```
for a in path:
   print(os.path.basename(path))
```

But that doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: "But that doesn't seem to be right." - Why?

Comment: The result just prints "a" multiple times rather than the directory of all the files in the folder a.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
import os

path = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Testing\\a"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        print("{root}\\{file}".format(root=root, file=file))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of file names in a folder using `listdir()`.

```
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Testing\\a"
l = os.listdir(path)
for a in l:
   print(path + a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a couple mistakes. You were using [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename), that only returns the name of the file or folder represented at the end of a path after the last file separator.

Instead, use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to get the full path of any file.

The other mistake was one of using the wrong variable inside the loop (`print(os.path.basename(path)` instead of using the variable `a`)

Also, dont forget to use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20listdir#os.listdir) to list the files inside the folder before looping.

```
import os
path = r"C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\Testing\a"
for file in os.listdir(path): #using a better name compared to a
   print(os.path.abspath(file)) #you wrote path here, instead of a. 
   #variable names that do not have a meaning 
   #make these kinds of errors easier to make, 
   #and harder to spot
```